# Chrysler A/C Stays Cold On Driver's Side When Set For Heat

Tags: chrysler

Restarting the car doesn't help; turning A/C on/off doesn't help.

Comment: Does it have “split” heating?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely a blend door actuator. These control the flaps which direct the air through the correct orifice (heater core or A/C evaporator) so you get the temperature you desire. Most newer cars with split automatic temp controls have blend door actuators controlled by the main controller. They are just small motors which are usually hard to get to and a PITB to change. Once the vehicle gets a little older, these are very likely to take a nose dive, no matter the manufacture of the automobile. They can usually be found through Amazon.com or other online sources, but you have to ensure that's what the problem is, usually be taking it out and testing it.

Comment: Depending on how new the car is sometimes the hvac controller loses it’s actuator calibration, this is especially true on chryslers.